# Fourier coefficients of $|\cos x|$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I’d like to find the Fourier coefficients of

$$ x(t) = |A \cos{ ( 2 \pi f_0 t )} | $$

I found that, without taking the absolute value, the coefficient for $k=1$ is $\frac A2$ but now I don’t know how to deal with the signal when the absolute value is taken. Can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know something about $f_0$?

Answer (score 0):

Split the integral.
If $2L=1/f_0$, then
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\frac 1L\int_{-L}^L|A \cos ( 2 \pi f_0 t ) |\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}Lt\right)\mathrm dt\\
&=\frac{|A|}L\int_{-L}^L\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi }Lt\right)\right|\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}Lt\right)\mathrm dt\\
&=\frac{|A|}\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\cos(x)|\cos(nx)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{|A|}\pi\int_{-\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{3\pi}2}|\cos(x)|\cos(nx)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{|A|}\pi\int_{-\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{\pi}2}|\cos(x)|\cos(nx)\mathrm dx
+\frac{|A|}\pi\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{3\pi}2}|\cos(x)|\cos(nx)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{|A|}\pi\int_{-\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\cos(x)\cos(nx)\mathrm dx
-\frac{|A|}\pi\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\frac{3\pi}2}\cos(x)\cos(nx)\mathrm dx\\
&=-\frac{4|A|}\pi\frac{\cos^3(\pi n/2)}{n^2 - 1}
\end{align}
On the other hand $b_n=0$.

Comment: The results should be $x_k= \frac {-2A}{\pi} \frac{(-1)^k}{4(k^2) - 1 } $ and can I use $e^{-2\pi k f_0 t } $ instead of the cos you used Or it’s wrong ?